# Using OpenSSL with a Java Applet

Tags: java

Hi I have a problem connecting a Java Applet client using SSL to a SSL Server

When I convert my project to a standard Java one it works but when I use
the source in an applet it does not connect.

I have tried signing the jar, different browsers, nothing seems to work!

Could anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

This applet needs server authentication.

Comment: "I have tried signing the jar"  Were you prompted to *trust* the digitally signed code?  Once an applet is trusted, it should be able to reach across sites & get any resource the foreign server is willing to provide to a Java app.

Answer (score 1):

If I understood you properly, then your application works properly as a standalone Java app, but not as an applet. That is most likely due to the security policy for the applet missing important rights.

In the Java console, you should see exceptions for failed security checks. Do you see any?

Answer (score 1):

What have you done? Are you directly using OpenSSL (with some external library), or are you using the SSL-functions build in into your Java VM (with SSLSocket and similar)?

- To use external (non-java) libraries, you need to have your applet signed, and supposedly you have to do other complicated stuff to be able to actually load the library.
- Using the build-in SSL functions should work in Applets (without any extra permissions), too. There has been a bug in Apple's implementation for Mac OS, so make sure you update your Java VM (it is fixed in the latest version). And Ubuntu's IcedTea plugin (OpenJDK) seems to have copied the bug from Mac OS (and not fixed yet) - use the Sun plugin there instead.
- Of course, from applets you can only access the server the applet came from (independently of using SSL or not), if the applet is not signed and granted the necessary permissions.